# win32 singleton with std containers CRT false memory leak?

Tags: winapi

How do i get rid of the false memory leak message from CRT ?

I have a singleton class defined as:

```
Singleton & Singleton::GetInstance()
{
    static Singleton_instance;
    return _instance;
}
```

and it contains the member

```
std::vector<float> somefloats;
```

and my main look something like this

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
   ..
   _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
   return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

It seems like the static instance is destroyed only after _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() is called resulting in a false memory output from CRT. How do i get rid of these messages ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10301083/2440728; https://stackoverflow.com/a/5266164/2440728

Comment: @VuVirt thanks bro it works! Sorry for the repost